# Is adding a class or id to a heading tag good practice?

Tags: html, css

If my headings are already in a div class is it still good practice to give the headings their own class or id.
For example...

```
<h6 class="general-question"></h6>
```

or

```
<h5 id="specific-question"></h5>
```

Comment: if you need to have an id or a class for an heading for styling or coding purpose, it's fine. anyway you could retrieve them with `.parentclass h<n>`

Comment: It all depends on what you need and your unique circumstances. The question is subjective and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to give any id or class to the heading tag if the heading tag is already wrap with a div class. But if you have multiple heading tags or more than one same heading tags in your div and you want to give different styles to the each of the heading tag then you need to give a id or class to each of the tags so that you can give different styles every tags.

Comment: If thats the point, still you dont need to give no `id` or `class` you have the option `nth-child` selector.

Comment: yes of course you can use it. The main fact is you have to use id or class where necessary. If you can do any work without using any id or class then don't use it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you have to use it more than once. An ID is only allowed be to be used once. A class can be used multiple times.